# How to set global headers for token in plain JavaScript without axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

How to set global headers like this

```
import axios from 'axios';

export default function setAuthToken (token) {
  axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${token}`;
  } else {
    delete axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization];
  }
}
```

But in plain javascript without axios

Comment: Why don't you want to use Axios? It's a really helpful tool for this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI your code seems to be missing some of the `if` statement.

It's not quite clear what you're asking but basically `XMLHttpRequest` (xhr) is how you make requests in "plain javascript".

It's pretty well documented on the MDN website.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest

Basically you would instantiate an xhr then to set the header you could run something like `xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);`

If you want it to be a default, one idea is to use a function that creates your xhr objects as needed and in the process sets this header.